# How to solve this limit using only limit laws? [$\lim_{x\to 2} {f(x) -5 \over x-2} = 3 $]

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$
\lim_{x\to 2} {f(x) -5 \over x-2} = 3 .  \quad \text{Find} \lim_{x \to 2}f(x).
$$

In the following limit, my initial thought process was to use the limit law:
$$
\lim_{x\to c} {g(x) \over h(x)} = {\lim_{x \to c} g(x) \over \lim_{x \to c} h(x)}  
$$

But this only applies when $\lim_{x \to c} h(x) \not= 0$ if I'm correct.
In this case however, that doesn't hold so I shouldn't be able to use this to find $f(x)$. But then how else am I supposed to solve this.

My working was this:
$$
\lim_{x\to 2} {f(x) -5 \over x-2} = 3 \\
\implies \lim_{x \to 2} f(x) -5 = 0 \\
\implies \lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = 5
$$

This is an exercise question from Thomas' Calculus (12 ed.) from the limits and continuity chapter. And the answer for this exercise is apparently correct, but this feels very wrong and something doesn't fit in.

Comment: You won't have a unique answer, as you can multiply whatever f you find (like below) by any function that goes to 1 as $x\to 2$,  for instance $(x-1)^n$ for any $n$

Comment: Are you sure you copied the question correctly?

Comment: Are you sure the question asks for $f(x)$ and not $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to2}f(x)$?

Comment: @Alan $f(x)=(x-1)*(3x-1)=3x^2-3x-x+1$ the limit with that f(x) is not $3$

Comment: It asked for the limit ,my bad for not specifying it...

Comment: Write expression under limit as $g(x) $ and then you know $\lim_{x\to 2}g(x)=3$. Write $f(x) $ in terms of $g(x) $ and evaluate limit of $f(x) $ using limit laws.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I feel that this question doesn't stand up to the standards of the community and could perhaps be better resolved on other sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit can only be finite if $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 2}(f(x)-5) = 0$. You can characterize $f$ as
$$
f(x) - 5  = \varphi(x) (x-2) \Leftrightarrow f(x)=5+\varphi(x)(x-2),
$$

with $\varphi(2) = 3$.

---

As it turns out, the original exercise only asked for $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 2}f(x)$...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$$
\lim_{x\to 2} {f(x) -5 \over x-2} = 3 \quad
$$
Set $f(2)-5=0$ to apply the  L Hospital rule:
$$
\lim_{x\to 2} {f'(x)} = 3
$$
We must have $f'(2)=3$, so $f'(x)$ should be differentiable at $x=2$

Thus, any general function with the
property $f(2)=5$ and $f'(2)=3$ will do.

---

As mentioned by zwim, the definition of the derivative is formally used to realize the conditions above.

By setting $f(2)=5$:

$$
f'(2)=\lim_{x\to 2}{f(x)-f(2)\over x-2}=3$$

Again, we see the sufficient conditions:

$$f(2)=5$$
$$f'(2)=3$$

---

For example, the functions:
$$f(x)=3x-1$$
$$f(x)=x^2-x+3$$
$$ f(x) ={e^{3x}\over e^6}+4$$

satisfy both the conditions above

Comment: Rather than invoking l'Hospital, using the definition of the derivative appears more natural $\dfrac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}\to f'(2)$.

Comment: The function $(x-1)(3x-1)$ is not such a function right?

Comment: @Pax Daga it is not

Comment: @mkcpz: Those conditions are not necessary—rather, they are sufficient. The function $f$ need not be defined at $2$.

Comment: @mkcpz: Also, I'm not sure using L'Hôpital's rule is correct here. You don't know that $f'$ is continuous at $2$. If $f$ satisfies $f'(2)=3$, and $f(2)=5$, then $\lim_{x\to 2} {f(x) -5 \over x-2} = 3$, but it is not necessarily true that $\lim_{x\to 2}f'(x)=3$ ($f'$ might well have an essential discontinuity at $2$).

Comment: We have no indication that $f$ is differentiable...